# Error when checking model target: expected predictions to have shape (None, 1000) but got array with shape (64, 2)

Tags: deep-learning, keras, kaggle, keras-layer, imagenet

Notebook so far: [Notebook](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h8gbliyt76bsurr/vgg_own.ipynb?dl=0)

I am trying to reshape the standard `Keras` `VGG16` model to use for the classic cats vs dogs competition ([Kaggle Cats vs Dogs](https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition))

I had to recreate the `pop()` and `add()` functions of the `Sequential()` Keras model to remove the last `Dense(1000)` layer and replace it with `Dense(2)` layer.

However, when I try to use the `fit_generator()` function, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected predictions to have shape (None, 1000) but got array with shape (64, 2)
```

It sounds like my model is still expecting to output 1000 categories rather than 2. Why is this?

Model summary below:

```
Layer (type) Output Shape Param # Connected to
input_27 (InputLayer) (None, 224, 224, 3) 0

block1_conv1 (Convolution2D) (None, 224, 224, 64) 1792 input_27[0][0]

block1_conv2 (Convolution2D) (None, 224, 224, 64) 36928 block1_conv1[0][0]

block1_pool (MaxPooling2D) (None, 112, 112, 64) 0 block1_conv2[0][0]

block2_conv1 (Convolution2D) (None, 112, 112, 128) 73856 block1_pool[0][0]

block2_conv2 (Convolution2D) (None, 112, 112, 128) 147584 block2_conv1[0][0]

block2_pool (MaxPooling2D) (None, 56, 56, 128) 0 block2_conv2[0][0]

block3_conv1 (Convolution2D) (None, 56, 56, 256) 295168 block2_pool[0][0]

block3_conv2 (Convolution2D) (None, 56, 56, 256) 590080 block3_conv1[0][0]

block3_conv3 (Convolution2D) (None, 56, 56, 256) 590080 block3_conv2[0][0]

block3_pool (MaxPooling2D) (None, 28, 28, 256) 0 block3_conv3[0][0]

block4_conv1 (Convolution2D) (None, 28, 28, 512) 1180160 block3_pool[0][0]

block4_conv2 (Convolution2D) (None, 28, 28, 512) 2359808 block4_conv1[0][0]

block4_conv3 (Convolution2D) (None, 28, 28, 512) 2359808 block4_conv2[0][0]

block4_pool (MaxPooling2D) (None, 14, 14, 512) 0 block4_conv3[0][0]

block5_conv1 (Convolution2D) (None, 14, 14, 512) 2359808 block4_pool[0][0]

block5_conv2 (Convolution2D) (None, 14, 14, 512) 2359808 block5_conv1[0][0]

block5_conv3 (Convolution2D) (None, 14, 14, 512) 2359808 block5_conv2[0][0]

block5_pool (MaxPooling2D) (None, 7, 7, 512) 0 block5_conv3[0][0]

flatten (Flatten) (None, 25088) 0 block5_pool[0][0]

fc1 (Dense) (None, 4096) 102764544 flatten[0][0]

fc2 (Dense) (None, 4096) 16781312 fc1[0][0]

predictions (Dense) (None, 2) 8194 fc2[0][0]
Total params: 134,268,738
Trainable params: 8,194
Non-trainable params: 134,260,544
```

The `.add()` function sets the `model.built` variable to False, so I am wondering if it's anything to do with that. And if it is, how do I "build" the model? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a pre-trained model to load it ? It could be an explanation.